# Parameterized Leading Zeros in C++ printf function

Tags: c++, printf

my question is simple. I want to print integers with a specified amount of leading zeros, using printf. However, the number of leading zeros is decided runtime, not known a priori. How could I do that?

If I knew the number of characters (let's say 5), it would be

```
printf("%05d", number);
```

But I don't know if it will be 5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass a width using `*`:

```
printf("%0*d", 5, number);
```

Comment: Except that in your example, you're passing a width, not a precision.  The precision must be preceded by a `'.'`, e.g. `printf("%.*d", 5, number)`.

Comment: @JamesKanze Right, I fixed that mistake.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use

```
cout << setw(width_) << setfill('0') << integerVariable_;
```

where `width_` is decided at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, that would workm, but in my case I needed to use printf. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I belive the asterisk can be used to achieve this on most platforms.

```
int width = whatever();
printf("%0*d", width, number );
```

Comment: This is C standard (for the `printf` family).  Regretfully, it's not supported in iostream---the precision field is ignored in integral output.

Comment: @Ivan K Rafal already provided the same answer please don't repeat the answer rather use comments for slight changes.

Comment: @amod0017: why? As you can see the author still did not update it, and hard coded a value! I prefer this answer in its current form since it is really parametrized.

Comment: @Ipapp I think he could have just suggested an edit rather then just doing a smart copy paste.

Answer (score 2):

The standard solution here would be `printf("%.*d", precision, number)`;
in the `printf` family, in C, the precision formatting field specifies a
minimum number of digits to be displayed, defaulting to 1.  This is
independent of the width, so you can write things like:

```
printf("%6.3d", 12);    // outputs "   012"
printf("%6.0d",  0);    // outputs "      ", without any 0
```

For either the width or the precision (or both), you can specify `'*'`,
which will cause `printf` to pick the value up from an argument (pass an 
`int`):

```
printf("%6.*d", 3, 12); // outputs "   012"
printf("%*.3d", 6, 12); // outputs "   012"
printf("%*.*d", 6, 3, 12);  // outputs "   012"
```

Regretfully, there is no equivalent functionality in `ostream`: the
precision is ignored when outputting an integer.  (This is probably
because there is no type dependent default for the precision.  The
default is 6, and it applies to all types which respect it.)

Answer (score -1):

use manipulators available in C++ setw and setfill.